# getting #error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=AADSTS70005: with token request

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to implement a OAuth2 implicit grant flow in an IOS app. In this case it requires a token request instead of a code request because you can't share the client secret in a native app safely.

so a request like this yields a login form:

```
https://login.windows.net/<tenantid>/oauth2/authorize?api-version=1.0&client_id=<client id>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=shp-apps://localhost:44300/?ReturnUrl=%2F&resource=https://graph.windows.net
```

After successfully login I get this error:

```
#error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=AADSTS70005: response_type 'token' 
  is not supported for the application
Trace+ID: 9008e580-2798-4b6c-a6bf-2bf614b61f64
Correlation+ID: ceb9bb4b-34a4-4441-801f-377f534543b1
Timestamp: 2014-08-26+16%3a24%3a24Z
```

Is this actually correct, the token request_type is not supported? or is there something else that I need to do? The application is setup as a native app. I have already been able to do a 'code' response_type in a different application in the same active directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit grant flow is indeed not supported yet by Azure AD. For your iOS app, use the authorization code grant flow with refresh token support. You don't need to write the OAuth flow on your own - use our iOS/OSX SDK instead: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc

Philip, stay tuned on the implicit grant flow - it is on our radar.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE: Azure AD now suports implicit grant OAuth flow. see: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. This work was to prep for testing out a few different identity providers, one of which was ADFS. So the active directory library wasn't going to be the best fit. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Let me know if you have more questions. By the way, ADFS 2012R2 as an IdP supports OAuth code flow, and our ADAL libraries work with it. Consider that for your whiteboarding.

Comment: @DushyantGill just stumpling over this - getting the same exception. I am trying to use jQuery to perform the OAuth2 Implicit Grant Flow. I have modified this example: https://www.itunity.com/article/calling-office-365-apis-jquery-adaljs-2758 . I have simply changed client ID and tenant with my values. Could it be that jQuery does not support OAuth2 Implicit Grant Flow? When using the example here with Angular.js : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/tree/master/ToGoAPI I have no problem logging in through my Office365 tenant.

Answer (score 2):

According to the MSDN Documentation on [AAD Auth Failures - Implicit OAuth is not enabled for the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/troubleshooting/auth/aadauth-enableimplicitoauth), you need to set `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to `true` in the App Registration Manifest in the Azure Portal.

#### The Issue

When creating your app registration in AAD, you need to manually edit the application manifest and set the value of the `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` property to `true`. Otherwise the AAD sign in flow will not work

> error "AADSTS70005: response_type 'token' is not supported for the application..."

#### The Solution

Follow these steps to solve this issue.

1. Sign into **portal.azure.com** with an administrator account in your tenant.
2. Navigate to **Azure Active Directory** in the left hand side bar > **App registrations** > **Your app**.
3. Click **Manifest** at the top of the pane describing your app.
4. Change the value of the property `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to `true`. If the property is not present, add it and set its value to `true`.

   [image]
5. Click "Save" to save the modified manifest.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Comment: This post is an exact duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49131396).

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Your edits [are](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49131396/revisions) completely [identical](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49131413/revisions). So we're still at the same problem, just without the fact that the post didn't qualify as an actual answer