# Authorizing Xamarin PCL app with Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I am developing a Xamarin PCL app using Xamarin.Forms and have a requirement to log in to it through Azure Active Directory. I have tried to achieve this by using Xamarin.Auth, however it seems that Azure AD doesn't support implicit grant flow as pointed out in the following link:

[getting #error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=AADSTS70005: with token request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511096/getting-error-unsupported-response-typeerror-description-aadsts70005-with-tok)

I am receiving the same error as described in that link. Does anyone have any idea how to go about this? I basically just want to be able to load the following page : https://login.microsoftonline.com/, log in using my azure active directory and on receiving a valid token, load the first page of my app. This is a requirement for all 3 platforms (Android, iOS and WP8), although right now I am just trying to get it to work on Android.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in Azure AD we don't uswe the implicit flow for native clients - we use a public client version of the authorization code grant. If you want to work with AAD and Xamarin in a PCL we have a preview of the next version of our libraries, you can find more details in http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/30/adal-net-v3-preview-pcl-xamarin-support/. Note that such library is a very early preview that WILL change and that cannot be used in production at this point. An alternative is using Xamarin bindings to our iOS and Android native libraries, but those aren't suitable for a PCL.