# Acquiring a token for graph.microsoft.com with adal.js

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I've been using Azure Active Directory and adal.js to authorize web apps client side and it's worked great. Recently had a request to have user photo instead of a generic user icon.

I added Microsoft Graph permissions to the app registration. And tried to get a token for the user photo request like...

```
authContext.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com', callback);
```

Which resulted in the `response_type 'token' is not supported for the application` error. So I found [ADAL JS - response_type="token" is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326918/adal-js-response-type-token-is-not-supported) suggesting setting `"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true` in the app manifest, which I did. Now I get `Token renewal operation failed due to timeout` error.

I've also added `'https://graph.microsoft.com': 'https://graph.microsoft.com'` to the `endpoints` prop of the context config.

What do I have to do get this working? Way too much time spent just trying to get users' photos. Thanks.

Comment: Can you see if any of the cases in this Adal.js [FAQ](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs#q7-token-renewal-operation-failed-due-to-timeout) for the token renewal timeout error apply to your app?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? thanks