# unsupported response type in oauth

Tags: .net, angular, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 2. I have oauth authentication in webapi. I am using Angular 2 in front end. On login I am calling below code.

```
   private login() {
        this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
        this.oauthService.loginUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/d35ba220-6896666-4acc-9899-dc75131c4fba/oauth2/authorize?resource=\"https://graph.windows.net/ \"& response_type=code";
        this.oauthService.redirectUri = "http://localhost:65298";
        this.oauthService.clientId = "<MY_CLIENT_ID>";
        this.oauthService.issuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/d35ba220-6749-4acc-578787-dc75131c4fba";
        this.oauthService.oidc = true;
        this.oauthService.setStorage(sessionStorage);
        this.oauthService.tryLogin({});
    }
```

I am getting below error.

```
http://localhost:65298/?error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=AADSTS70005%3a+
The+WS-Federation+sign-in+response+message+contains+an+unsupported+OAuth+parameter+value+in+the+encoded+wctx%3a+%27response_type%27%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+65dc2592-4ba1-42f6-9f24-eba1c1894900%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+6edaf003-3d26-434b-9b8a-88a267feb350%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-01-17+09%3a09%3a39Z&state=9MnA2eD68aZtOvHSodIjX9IqA1NdSjslrnGaFAlL
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

According to the MSDN Documentation on [AAD Auth Failures - Implicit OAuth is not enabled for the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/troubleshooting/auth/aadauth-enableimplicitoauth), you need to set `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to `true` in the App Registration Manifest in the Azure Portal.

#### The Issue

When creating your app registration in AAD, you need to manually edit the application manifest and set the value of the `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` property to `true`. Otherwise the AAD sign in flow will not work

> error "AADSTS70005: response_type 'token' is not supported for the application..."

#### The Solution

Follow these steps to solve this issue.

1. Sign into **portal.azure.com** with an administrator account in your tenant.
2. Navigate to **Azure Active Directory** in the left hand side bar > **App registrations** > **Your app**.
3. Click **Manifest** at the top of the pane describing your app.
4. Change the value of the property `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to `true`. If the property is not present, add it and set its value to `true`.

   [image]
5. Click "Save" to save the modified manifest.

Comment: I love you. ❤ Took me half a day of pulling my hair out. Did Microsoft tutorial on how to connect to Dynamics API, it tells you how to create the App Registration, create postman requests, set the grant type to implicit in the request, and it doesn't ever mention this flag.

Comment: I'm using Angular 8 with microsoft-adal-angular6  and I had to set `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` to true instead

Comment: You can just check the box: Authentication > Access tokens

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using OAuth2 Implicit Grant flow to authenticate your application, you'll need to set the response type to `id_token`, `token` or `id_token token` instead of `code`.

You'll also need set the "*oauth2AllowImplicitFlow*" value to `true` in the AAD application's manifest file.

Comment: where to add this "you'll need to set the response type to id_token, token or id_token token instead of code"